# Deprecated NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData

Tags: swift

I get some issues while trying to fix deprecated method.
Before the deprecation, I was saving my Array of CustomClass like follows:

```
data =  try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tabCustomObj, requiringSecureCoding: true)
```

Then I was recovering the data with :

```
 try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [CustomClass]
```

From the non deprecated method I use this following:

```
try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CustomClass.self, from: data)
```

For me it was the equivalent with the new method, but it looks failing and it works only with one object. For now, so I do not deprecate my code but for the future it will be problem, if someone has the same issue (or I miss something)?

Comment: have you tried: `try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: [CustomClass.self], from: data) as? [CustomClass]`

Comment: thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine yes but it gives two errors; `Static method 'unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[CustomClass]' conform to 'NSSecureCoding' ` and `Static method 'unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[CustomClass]' inherit from 'NSObject'`

Comment: @ek88 `try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CustomClass.self, from: data)` is correct. Can you please edit your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus I finally identify the issue probably due to the previous version that looks not compatible with decodeObject when using and array.

Answer (score 1):

When the `CustomClass` conforms to `NSObject and NSSecureCoding`
as shown in the example code, the decoding works for me.

Here is my test code that uses your original `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass:...)` to recover an array of `[CustomClass]`.

```
let arr = [CustomClass(name: "name1"), CustomClass(name: "name2")]

do {
   let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arr, requiringSecureCoding: true)
   
   let decodeArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CustomClass.self, from: data)

   decodeArray?.forEach{ print("---> item: \($0.name)") }
   
} catch {
   print("\n---> error: \(error)\n")
}

class CustomClass: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    }
    
}
```

Note it also works with

```
 let decodeArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClasses: [CustomClass.self], from: data) as? [CustomClass]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feefback, By comparing the working example, it was exactly a comparable situation. I finally identify the problem, I was decoding an attribute inside my `CustolmClass` that was containing an array of NSValue and I was decoding it using:

```
  myTab = coder.decodeObject(forKey:"keytab") as? [NSValue]
```

It works when MyCustomClass use the deprecated method and fails when using the non deprecated method to decode the tabular of CustomClass objects. When using the new version to decode myTab inside my CustomClass it fix the issue:

```
  myTab = coder.decodeArrayOfObjects(ofClass: NSValue.self,
                                     forKey: "keytab")
```

Thanks to the working base exemple, it put me on the right track to identify the issue!

Answer (score -1):

Ek88 is exactly what happened to me, for arrays in NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: you must use coder.decodeArrayOfObjects